# Errors when trying to compile java file

Tags: java, compilation, compiler-errors

I get several errors when trying to compile with java. This is my first post on stack overflow, so please point out mistakes in my post.

The code is some test code i made for a practical.

The following is my code:

```
public class MiscUtilsTest
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    testMax();
    testCalcGrade();
    testRoomArea();
    }

    public static void testMax()
    {
    int num, num2, num3;

    num = MiscUtils.max(9, 2);
    assert 9 == num;

    num2 = MiscUtils.max(6, 1);
    assert 6 == num2;

    num3 = MiscUtils.max(7, 7);
    assert 7 == num3;

    }

    public static void testCalcGrade()
    {
    int grade1, grade2, grade3, grade4, grade5, grade6, grade7, grade8, grade9;

    grade1 = MiscUtils.calcGrade(2);
    assert "F".equals(grade1);

    grade2 = MiscUtils.calcGrade(15);
    assert "F".equals(grade2);

    grade3 = MiscUtils.calcGrade(28);
    assert "F".equals(grade3);

    grade4 = MiscUtils.calcGrade(33);
    assert "F".equals(grade4);

    grade5 = MiscUtils.calcGrade(40);
    assert "F".equals(grade5);

    grade6 = MiscUtils.calcGrade(49);
    assert "F".equals(grade6);

    grade7 = MiscUtils.calcGrade(82);
    assert "8".equals(grade7);

    grade8 = MiscUtils.calcGrade(125);
    assert "".equals(grade8);

    grade9 = MiscUtils.calcGrade(-12);
    assert "".equals(grade9);

    }

    public static void testRoomArea()
    {
    int test, test2, test3;

    test2 = MiscUtils.roomArea(-10, 5);
    assert 0 == test;

    test2 = MiscUtils.roomArea(6, 2);
    assert 0 == test2;

    test3 = MiscUtils.roomArea(5, 10);
    assert 50 == test3;

    }
}
```

---

The following is the errors i get while while compiling -

```
MiscUtilsTest.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
MiscUtilsTest.java:30: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int
    grade1 = MiscUtils.calcGrade(2);
                                ^
MiscUtilsTest.java:33: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int
    grade2 = MiscUtils.calcGrade(15);
                                ^
MiscUtilsTest.java:36: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int
    grade3 = MiscUtils.calcGrade(28);
                                ^
MiscUtilsTest.java:39: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int
    grade4 = MiscUtils.calcGrade(33);
                                ^
MiscUtilsTest.java:42: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int
    grade5 = MiscUtils.calcGrade(40);
                                ^
MiscUtilsTest.java:45: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int
    grade6 = MiscUtils.calcGrade(49);
                                ^
MiscUtilsTest.java:48: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int
    grade7 = MiscUtils.calcGrade(82);
                                ^
MiscUtilsTest.java:51: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int
    grade8 = MiscUtils.calcGrade(125);
                                ^
MiscUtilsTest.java:54: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int
    grade9 = MiscUtils.calcGrade(-12);
                                ^
9 errors
```

For those asking about the class file, Code from MiscUtils.class

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class MiscUtils
{
static
{
    System.out.println("[FYI: You are testing the *working* version of MiscUtils. Your test harness *should not* find any problems.]");
 }

public static int max(int paramInt1, int paramInt2)
{
    int i = paramInt1;
    if (paramInt2 > paramInt1) {
    i = paramInt2;
    }
    return i;
}

public static String calcGrade(int paramInt)
{
    String str = "";
    if ((paramInt >= 0) && (paramInt <= 100)) {
    if (paramInt >= 50) {
    str = str + paramInt / 10;
    } else {
    str = "F";
    }
    }
    return str;
}

public static int roomArea(int paramInt1, int paramInt2)
{
    int i = 0;
    if ((paramInt1 > 0) && (paramInt2 >= paramInt1) && (paramInt2 <= 3 * paramInt1)) {
    i = paramInt1 * paramInt2;
 }
    return i;
}
}
```

Comment: For starters, you could also post the code of the `MiscUtils` class.

Comment: Could you post MiscUtils

Comment: We do not want the .class. Include the code used for defining MiscUtils in your question, please. If MiscUtils is defined in MiscClassUtilsTest.java,  edit your question and copy the code there.

Comment: I have added the MiscUtils.class code

Comment: Java is case sensitive. If you have a method named "calcGrade", you must invoke "calcGrade" and not "CalcGrade".

Comment: Thanks for the help, that fixed the errors, but i now have new errors. i posted them and replaced my old errors

Comment: Are you not using an IDE like eclipse?? If not, you should. It will clear most of your doubts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you MiscUtils class is missing the methods shown in the compiler errors.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/klhhl3ng1sa7n5x/MiscUtils.class.working?dl=0                  The class file is here, i am unsure how to open/read it.

Answer (score 0):

You have not imported the class MiscUtils. Thus its giving error.

Use import syntax before class MiscUtilsTest.

```
import MiscUtils.*;
```

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
 int grade1, grade2, grade3, grade4, grade5, grade6, grade7, grade8, grade9;
```

to

```
String grade1, grade2, grade3, grade4, grade5, grade6, grade7, grade8, grade9;
```

Since `calcGrade()` returns a `String` and not an `int`.

Comment: Thank you so much, i received several other errors while compiling, but i managed to fix them. Thanks for the help all, managed to compile with no errors. Also, from now on i'll be sure to eliminate these mistakes :)